# How can I read .djvu files on Kindle?

Tags: file-format, kindle, djvu

I received some weird science books in .djvu format.
Would like to put them on a Kindle.

Found some obscure software which I can use for that i.e. http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/, but I have no way to assess if it's a good or optimal way.

What ways would you use?
I strive for simplicity.